# Redux saga, rx-observable. With vanilla fetch calls, why the need over thunks?

Tags: redux, redux-saga, redux-observable

I have been reading about sagas, their intent, and their usage. BUT - I have two questions that I'd really like some closure on, and then more of an opinion question.

1. When using Sagas for a simple api call, the boilerplate seems very excessive. If I had 20 api calls, how is that less wieldy than using thunks? Plus, I keep hearing the idea of "side effects" - but I'm unsure how that plays into it all.

I read some blogs that used a pattern that was able to dynamically generate the Sagas to reduce less boilerplate - but couldn't you do that with thunks too? Also, any examples would be great.

1. Are Sagas still usefull when literally dealing with very simple post or get calls?

---

Any opinions on redux-sags vs. redux-observables?

thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Disclaimer: I am one of the authors of redux-observable, so my opinions of both redux-saga and redux-observable are tainted with bias**

Since you used the term Saga (instead of Epic) I'll assume you're asking in the context of redux-saga (not redux-observable).

In redux-saga, the effects you do, e.g. an AJAX request, aren't actually directly handled inside your generator sagas. Instead, the helpers you use are creating Plain Old JavaScript Objects which *represent* the effect **intent**, which you `yield` and then the redux-saga middleware itself performs the effect internally, hidden from you, providing the results back to your yield, like `yourSaga.next(response)`.

Some like this because your saga generators are truly pure. Because it uses generators to support multiple effects, it makes it easy to test without mocks because you just assert that the effects it yielded are expected. Personally, I found in practice this seemed far cooler than it really is: many times you end up effectively recreating everything the saga does in your test. You are now testing the *implementation* of the saga is correct not testing the *behavior* of the saga. Many don't care (or even notice this), but I did. I imagine some even prefer it. This is called "effects as data". FWIW, redux-observable does not use this "effects as data" model, which is the most fundamental difference between it and redux-saga.

Tying this back to how they compare to redux-thunk, the biggest differences are: time-based operations (e.g. debouncing sequential actions) are impractical with redux-thunk alone without major hacks. Speaking of debouncing, it doesn't come with any utilities at all, so you're on the your handling debouncing and other common effects. Testing is much much harder.

These are mostly opinions, however. Certainly very successful applications can (and have) use redux-thunk. https://m.twitter.com comes to mind.

I think it wouldn't be controversial to say that redux-thunk is significantly easier to learn and use for simple request->response AJAX calls, without needing cancellation, etc. In fact, I often recommend users unfamiliar with RxJS use redux-thunk for the simple stuff and only lean on redux-observable for the more complex stuff, so they can remain productive and learn as they go. There's definitely a place for academic "correctness" and beautiful code, but for most people's jobs, shipit™ should be #1 priority. Users don't care how correct our code is, only that it exists and [mostly] works.

---

Regarding opinions on redux-saga vs. redux-observable, I'm biased because I'm one of the authors of redux-observable, but I summarized some of my thoughts in a previous SO post: [Why use Redux-Observable over Redux-Saga?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40021344/why-use-redux-observable-over-redux-saga/40027778#40027778) tl;dr they have a similar overall pattern, but redux-saga uses "effects as data" whereas redux-observable uses real effects with RxJS. Pros and cons to both, the primary pro to using RxJS that it is a skill that is a vastly useful skill for things other than redux-observable, and will almost certainly outlive redux-observable/redux-saga so the skill is highly transferable.