# What would I use for start async Redux out of following Thunk or Saga or Observable or Redux Promise Middleware?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I finished the Lynda learning react native course. Now I started learning #Redux but for redux async flow we have 
1.Thunk 
2.Saga 
3.Observable 
4.Redux Promise Middleware

So I got confuse in selecting any one. Which must be easy to understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Redux Thunk is the basic one. I would use that for a simple app.

Redux Thunk with async/await will provide with all the tools you need to do your Ajax and async logic.

If your app is complicated, then you can use redux-saga/redux observable. Those are the most popular ones.

I would choose redux-observable mostly because Observable (RxJS) knowledge is transferable to other areas of your code [Why use Redux-Observable over Redux-Saga?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40021344/why-use-redux-observable-over-redux-saga)

Answer (score 0):

First start with Redux Thunk itself then u can move to other library, as you well experienced in future

Comment: Thunk and saga are quite similar. But Observable handles cancellation and many other asynchronous side effects by using reactive programming. If you are interested in reactive programming then go with Observable, it is awesome.