# How to debug Observable values in Angular2 / Typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, rxjs5

I have followed the tutorial for angular 2 and have a search functionality that renders a list of heroes asynchronously.

```
<div *ngFor="let hero of heroes | async">
    {{hero.name}}
</div>
```

In the component I have observable heroes:

```
heroes: Observable<Hero[]>;
```

Now I have implemented similar functionality in my application by I don't see anything and I don't see any errors either. I opened the debugger in Chrome and tried to check the value of heroes, but it's just some Observable wrapper of course.

Is there any way to see the current/last or some value in the debugger or maybe there is some other technique to debug such issues?

Comment: Hopefully, some tools to aid debugging RxJS will be built. Until then, you might find this useful: http://staltz.com/how-to-debug-rxjs-code.html And maybe this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38597548/6680611

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There're several article on this topic but most easily use [`do()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-do) operator to see what's going on in your operator chains.

Read more:

- https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/gettingstarted/testing.md#debugging-your-rx-application
- [How to debug rxjs5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38590346/how-to-debug-rxjs5)
- http://staltz.com/how-to-debug-rxjs-code.html
- https://react.rocks/example/rxvision
- http://jaredforsyth.com/2015/03/06/visualizing-reactive-streams-hot-and-cold/

Comment: So there is no way to use the debugger for that purpose if I understood correctly?

Comment: @IlyaChernomordik Of course you can use debugger. The problem is that it's not very helpful because there're so many nested calls and so many anonymous Observables and function that it's very hard keep track of what's going on inside. This is described also in the doc https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/gettingstarted/testing.md#long-stack-traces-support

Answer (score 13):

In RxJS v6+, the `tap()` operator has replaced `do()`. So it will look more like this now:

```
someObservable$.pipe(
  map(x => x.whatever),
  tap(whatever => console.log(whatever)),
)
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, if you're using typescript consider:

```
heroes: Observable<Array<Hero>>;
```

If you want to print it, you can simply add in your code:

```
heroes.subscribe((v) => console.log('got new heroes list: ', v));
```

Comment: So back to console logging and no debugging options? P.S. Why is Array<Hero> better than Hero[]? This is directly from Angular2 tutorial.

Comment: No pain no gain :-) But even stalz relate to the hardship of debugging.

As for Array<Item>, I find it more readable and consistant with the typed approach. Imagine Array<Array<Item>>, Item[][]? (Item[])[]? it gets messy.

Comment: The debugger (in Chrome at least) now allows fine-grained breakpoints. I was able to write a statement like in this answer, put a breakpoint directly on the log call, and then the Local Scope window showed the value of v as the materialized Observable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **do()** operator EX :

```
this.http
        .get('someUrl', options)
        .map(res => res.json())
        .do(
            data => {
                console.log(data);
            },
            error => {
                console.log(error)
            }
        )
```

If nothing happens inside the do() functions it means you are not subscribed to that observable, remember that observables are waiting for a subscription to start doing something.

Answer (score 1):

U can use  .pipe() to log as shown.

```
constructor(
    private variable: Variable<any>
  ) {
    this.field= this.variable.select<any>(state => state.field).pipe(
        tap(Value => console.log('Field: ', Value ))
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do some `console.log` debugging, I wrote a little helper `logValues()` in [`s-rxjs-utils`](https://simontonsoftware.github.io/s-rxjs-utils/typedoc/index.html#logvalues). You can use it like this (from the docs):

```
of(1, 2).pipe(logValues()).subscribe();
// prints using console.log:
// [value] 1
// [value] 2
// [complete]
```

You can also pass it a string to print along with the values, and specify the log level.