# How to test RxJS events

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs5, rxjs-dom

I'm handling a mouseover event using `Observable.fromEvent()`, with various chained operators. How would I go about unit testing this?

```
export const bindMouseover = (link) => Observable.fromEvent(link, 'mouseover')
    .filter(event => Nav.hasSubNav(event.target))
    .map(event => Nav.getSubNav(event.target))
    .filter(target => !Nav.elementIsVisible(target))
    .subscribe((target) => {
      Nav.hideElements(subNavs);
      Nav.showElement(target);
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a chapter on testing RxJS chains in the RxJS 4 documentation but the principles applies to RxJS 5 as well: https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/gettingstarted/testing.md

If you want to unit test RxJS custom operators or operator chains there's official documentation: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/writing-marble-tests.md (However, this document doesn't tell you where you can import features listed there in your own code).

Also, have a look at how RxJS is tested itself. For example [testing `map()` operator](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/spec/operators/map-spec.ts) (btw, these are `mocha` tests). Note how Hot and Cold Observables are made with this short notation `cold('--1--2--3--|')` and then compared with the expected `'--x--y--z--|'` using [`expectObservable` that comes from TestScheduler](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/260d335f497a2de223b164ea9705699e7f306d7d/src/testing/TestScheduler.ts#L75).

If you wanted to use also the short notation with `cold(...)`, `hot(...)` and others you'd need to grab the source code, compile it with `npm run build_test` and then use the same options for `mocha` as the original. [See `package.json`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/package.json#L91) and the default options for [`mocha` in `default.opts`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/spec/support/default.opts). I'm not aware of any easier solution right now.

The short notation just makes things easier and more readable but you don't need it in fact. You can use the regular test Observables (`TestScheduler`, `ColdObservable` and `HotObservable`) already since they're part of the standard `rxjs` package. https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/tree/master/src/testing (`node_modules/rxjs/testing`)

Also see: [How to debug Observable values in Angualr2 / Typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40256541/how-to-debug-observable-values-in-angualr2-typescript/40256977#40256977)

Comment: Hey! Thank you for your answer! Is it possible to somehow made rxjs working from real element events? 

I mean. I will trigger some events in the element and I expect that RxJS observable generated from `Observable.fromEvent` will emit some data. Is it possible somehow?